# Which is the favorite leaf of Lord Brahma?

Tags: rituals, brahma, plants

Lord Vishnu is fond of Tulasi leaves and Lord Shiva likes bilvam. So, similarly which leaf is favored by Lord Brahma?

Comment: Lord Bramha is never worshipped in home temples, there is only one temple in this world for Lord Bramha in pushkar you may want to ask them. Also Shriman Narayana (vishnu) is not fond of Tulsi, he granted boon to tulsi to always remain in his feet as a sharanagata so its true vice versa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Temple,_Pushkar.

Comment: YogiI slightly differ from your views. In trichy a temple named uttamarkoil is there in which trimurthys  Lord Brahma  Vishnu and Siva exist. It is the rarest  and very old temple. If you offer a leaf of tulsi and small quantity of water to Krishna he is the most happiest. He is fond of Tulsi and wherever in heaven so many tusi plants are found, In kodayin paadhai Lakshmi narasimhacharyar has quoted these.

Comment: lotus leaf because that is his home :)

Comment: @ram Any evidence that supports your answer

Comment: source for home or source for favorite flower? i was joking about favorite, but his home is that - brahma sits on a lotus flower emanating from perumal's nabhi